# Embed SSRS report in a HTML5/AngularJS page

Tags: .net, angularjs, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a project,

- frontend is standalone HTML5/AngularJS (NO ASP.NET)
- backend is .NET csharp
- SSRS 2012 for reports

I want to embed SSRS reports in an iframe. It always prompt for the login and password before report is displayed, and this is not acceptable.

Any suggestions on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the ssrs api instead of the url access. with that you can have it peel off the reports as html and tuck it into your IFrame.

If you want the toolbar functionality that comes with the report viewer toolbar you can to set the credentials via the rc commands, depending on what type authentication you are using, this can stop the prompt.

[This](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154493(v=sql.105).aspx) article describes how to pass credentials to the report viewer

Comment: Added a link to the report toolbar which can also provide the desired functionality. You have to configure a directory in your web to be a web application with a web.config. Then embed the Reportviewer control in an aspx page and call that page in your IFrame.